# In react native how to arrange image button

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react native.

I need to arrange 8 image button in 4 rows and 2 columns.I tried with flexDirection, but it's not work(confuse).
Actually i need to arrange my 8 image like below image in react native.(I need only 4 -rows,2 columns)

**Please help me..**

[image]
my code

`
container:{
            backgroundColor: '#ccffcc',

```
        flex:1,
        flexDirection: ('row'),
        //paddingTop: 40,
        //alignItems :'center',
        padding:10

      },
      button1:{
         flex:1,
        // width : 100,
        // height: 100,
        flexDirection:'row',
        backgroundColor : '#ff9933',
        //alignSelf:'flex-start',
        marginTop: 70,
        margin: 20,
        //justifyContent:'center'
      },
      button2:{

        //flex:1,
        //flexDirection:'column',
        alignSelf:'center',
        //height :50,
        //backgroundColor : '#ff9933',
        //alignSelf:'flex-start',
        margin: 20,
        marginTop:-30,
        //justifyContent:'center'
      },
      button3:{
        //flex:1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        // width : 100,
        // height: 100,
        backgroundColor : '#ff9933',
        alignSelf:'flex-start',
      //  marginTop:100,
        margin: 20,

        justifyContent:'center'
      },
      button4:{
        //flex:1,
      //  flexDirection: 'row',
        //height :50,
        //backgroundColor : '#ff9933',
        alignSelf:'flex-start',
        margin: 20,
      //  marginTop:30,
        justifyContent:'center'
      },
      button5:{
        flex:1,
        flexDirection:'column',
    // width : 100,
        // height: 100,
        backgroundColor : '#ff9933',
        alignSelf:'flex-end',
        //marginTop:50,
        margin: 20,

        justifyContent:'center'
      },
      button6:{
        flexDirection:'column',
        flex:1,
        //height :50,
        //backgroundColor : '#ff9933',
        alignSelf:'flex-end',
        margin: 20,
      //  marginTop:30,
        justifyContent:'center'
      },
      button7:{
        flexDirection:'column',
        flex:1,
       // width : 100,
        // height: 100,
        backgroundColor : '#ff9933',
        alignSelf:'flex-end',
      //  marginTop:100,
        margin: 20,

        justifyContent:'center'
      },
      button8:{
        flexDirection:'column',
        flex:1,    //height :50,
        //backgroundColor : '#ff9933',
        alignSelf:'flex-end',
        margin: 20,
      //  marginTop:30,
        justifyContent:'center'
      },`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by calculating the width of the container, then simply dividing the width by the number of items you need per row:

[image]

Check out [this](https://rnplay.org/apps/R_asoA) example I set up, also pasted the code below.

```
 "use strict";

var React = require("react-native");
var { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, ScrollView } = React;

var width = Dimensions.get("window").width - 20;
var images = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
render: function() {
    var icons = images.map((image, i) => {
        return (
            <View key={i} style={styles.listItemContainer}>
                <View style={styles.listItem}>
                    <Text style={{ backgroundColor: "transparent" }}>
                        Image {image}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    });

    return (
        <ScrollView style={{ flex: 1, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10 }}>
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={styles.list}>{icons}</View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    );
}
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1
},
list: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
    flex: 1,
    marginTop: 50
},
listItemContainer: {
    width: width / 4,
    height: width / 4
},
listItem: {
    backgroundColor: "#ededed",
    borderRadius: 15,
    margin: 10,
    flex: 1
}
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent("SampleApp", () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer .its work.One thing how to insert image button to it.

Comment: Sure, just replace the Text component with an Image component.

Comment: the thing is I want  separate functions for each button.

Comment: Oh, ok. Change out View for a TouchableHighlight, then pass down the function as a property (prop)

Answer (score 0):

you can use react native grid view here :

https://github.com/lucholaf/react-native-grid-view